# Why does distributed tensorflow timeline trace mark the QueueDequeue operation as a PS operation?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm running the tensorflow distributed inception model on a cluster of AWS ubuntu machines, and outputting timeline traces via

```
# Track statistics of the run using Timeline
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

# Run
loss_value, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

# Create timeline and write it to a json file
tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
with open('timeline%d.json' % FLAGS.task_id, 'w') as f:
f.write(ctf)
```

When I view the timeline generated by a worker machine I see this:
[Timeline Trace for Worker Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzTGs.png)

Note the QueueDequeue operation on the right, which the timeline says is part of /job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0, a parameter server.

Since ScatterUpdate is right after QueueDequeue as shown in the image, I believe this operation corresponds to the sync replicas optimizer operation where a worker tries to dequeue a token and do a scatter update: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py#L412

But if so, a worker should be executing this operation, not a parameter server. Why is the timeline saying that the parameter server is executing this?

I'm using tensorflow 0.11, CPU only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is correct and that the dequeue operation is executed on the PS. It's just that the worker has a dependency on this operation, which means the worker is essentially waiting for a successful dequeue.